# Retrieving contracts metadata given swarm hash file

Tags: contract-development, abi, swarm, meta-data

How can I retrieve the contract's metadata referred by Swarm Source at Etherscan page for this contract? https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984#code

It says the bzzr://68d42e51eae03f461fed8d2db904ba521e900521e0a2199b4a57d733502ad3da
and I am wondering if I will have to run a Swarm's bee local client in order to query/retrieve that file stored in that hash location.

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve this? I found a swarm gateway https://gateway.ethswarm.org/access/<SWARM_HASH> which provides metadata files, even though it doesn't work in most cases.